# Ajuda com codigo Javascript

Tags: javascript

Não entendi muito bem o que quiseram fazer neste código.
Deveria abrir uma Div com um formulário básico.

Meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SoliciteProposta = $.noConflict();
    function MostrarEsconderDiv(div) {

        var prefixo = "ContentPlaceHolderDefault_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_ctl02_SoliciteUmaProposta_5_";
        var hdnDiv = prefixo + "hdn" + div;

        if (document.getElementById(prefixo + div).style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById(prefixo + div).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(hdnDiv).value = "aberta";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(prefixo + div).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(hdnDiv).value = "";
        }
    }
</script>

<tr>
                        <td colspan="3" height="10">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                            <div class="Section">
                                <div class="SectionHeader">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img align="absMiddle" hspace="4" src="/images/internas/seta3.gif" />
                                                <a id="A3" class="linkFormularios" href="javascript:MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui</a>
                                                <%--  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAbrirSecao6" runat="server" ForeColor="#cc3333" Font-Size="small" Font-Bold="true" OnClientClick="return MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">
                                            Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                                --%>
                                                <br />
                                                (abrirá um formulário nesta mesma página para você preencher)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div id="spacer" style="margin-top: 5px">
                                </div>
                                <div id="divSecao6" style="display: none; margin-left: 30px" runat="server">
                                    <table id="idSecao6Table" width="100%">
                                        <!-- SECAO 6 -->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="15">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#ececec" height="21">
                                                <b>6 - Apenas para Sistema Integrado de Gestão</b>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                                                Responda a esta seção apenas se você estiver interessado em uma certificação integrada (opcional).
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <font color="#666666"><b>A Política e o Manual do Sistema de Gestão são integrados?</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPoliticaManualSistemaIntegrados" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sim" Text="Sim"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Não" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <font color="#666666"><b>Os procedimentos de gestão (ex: Controle Documentos, Auditorias) são integrados?</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblProcGestaoIntegrados" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sim" Text="Sim, pelo menos 80% dos procedimentos de gestão são integrados"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Não" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <font color="#666666"><b>Os procedimentos operacionais (ex: Controle de produção) são integrados?</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblProcOperacionaisIntegrados" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sim" Text="Sim, pelo menos 80% dos procedimentos operacionais são integrados"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Não" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!-- FIM - ESCONDE SEÇÃO 6  -->
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Qual sua dúvida exatamente? A div não está aparecendo?

Comment: Isso @FernandoMedeiros, não entendi muito bem o que o cara quis fazer, preciso que a div fique visível. Quero entender e arrumar esse código.

Comment: Cara basicamente o que a função faz é concatenar uma string passada como parametro com um valor pré definido e selecionar o elemento com essa string resultante, se o elemento estiver visivel ele esconde, caso contrario ele faz aparecer

Comment: A função é chamada cada vez que ocorre um click no elemento <a id="A3" class="linkFormularios" href="javascript:MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui</a>

Comment: Ah beleza, entendi certo então, só que tipo não está aparecendo ao clicar no link. Como posso modificar essa function para que fique visível ao clicar ?

Comment: você deve procurar qual é o elemento html que está agrupando o tal formulario que voce disse que deveria aparecer, procure pelo atributo id, achando-o mude o código da função MostrarEsconderDiv

Comment: veja em quais pontos da sua aplicação essa função é chamada, mas o fato de ele concatenar a string de parametro com o valor  ContentPlaceHolderDefault_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_ctl02_SoliciteUmaProposta_5_

Comment: é muito estranho,pois MUITO dificilmente haverá um atributo id com nome tão extenso, se o id do seu formulário for simplesmente "div6", faça com que essa string passada pelo parametro seja usada na função document.getElementById()

Comment: Mudaram a classe da div, através de um método: usando recurso display: block e display:none, e mudaram o valor dele, através de concatenação de variáveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que eu sugiro você a fazer:

Modificar a parte em que ocorre a concatenação da string ao parametro, pois é muito dificil existir algum elemento com id tão extenso

```
var prefixo = "ContentPlaceHolderDefault_ContentPlaceHolderDefault_ctl02_SoliciteUmaProposta_5_";
```

Modifique aonde ocorre isso:

```
document.getElementById(prefixo + div)
```

por:

```
document.getElementById(div)
```

Agora procure o ID do elemento de seus formulário que deve aparecer após acontecer o click do botão, e passe-o como parâmetro da função;

```
<a id="A3" class="linkFormularios" href="javascript:MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui</a>
                                            <%--  <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAbrirSecao6" runat="server" ForeColor="#cc3333" Font-Size="small" Font-Bold="true" OnClientClick="return MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">
                                        Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
```

Aonde está `MostrarEsconder("divSecao6")` troque o div6 pelo id de seu elemento do form

Caso isso não funcione crie uma nova função, copie o conteúdo da função atual e refaça as mudanças listadas acima, mude o evento de click do seu botao para chamar essa nova função, e passe como parametro o seu form, no caso acredito que o ID seja divSecao6

Comment: fora do projeto funcionou, mas dentro não cara. Estranho.

Comment: Aperte F12 usando o Chrome e veja o console

Comment: Já vi, não aparece nada relevante.

Comment: Agora deu: UncaughtTypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: Você precisa adicionar um atributo style ao elemento do form, coloque style="display:none"